# Just a simple masquerade

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Centuries have been achieved with my aid.
>   I wear my hair in one very long braid.
>
> Exploding cars you need? I'll get one made.
>   Please go and stand up in line till you've paid.
>
> Actors awaiting their turn in the shade.
>   Can you locate me in this masquerade?

Who am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Centuries have been achieved with my aid

> Cue - used to make 100+ breaks in snooker.

I wear my hair in one very long braid

> [queue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(hairstyle)) - the traditional Chinese male hairstyle of one long braid.
>   <sub>Original try: q - the single tail of the letter is your hair.</sub>

Exploding cars you need, I'll get one made.

> Q - the ingenious designer from James Bond.

Please go and stand in line till you've paid

> queue - waiting in line to pay at the till.

Actors awaiting their turn in the shade

> cue - for actors to take their part on stage.

Can you locate me in this masquerade.

> mas**q**uerade

Comment: haha much better than my answer :)

Comment: @1848 - your answer is classically excellent and very interesting!

Comment: Correct again. You're a beast. I was thinking about something else for line 2, though :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually I think that the Tom's answer is the correct solution, but here is one that fits almost too easily:

> film, as in movies

Centuries have been achieved with my aid.

> Cinema, though not old itself, can and does depict many ages. Also 20th Century Fox, as suggested by LinuxBlanket.

I wear my hair in one very long braid.

> Film is wound up on a reel in one long strip

Exploding cars you need? I'll get one made.

> Exploding cars are a staple of many action movies.

Please go and stand up in line till you've paid.

> People often wait in line for a movie ticket on opening nights for popular titles.

Actors awaiting their turn in the shade.

> Actors play in films (duh!).

Can you locate me in this masquerade?

> Films are all about roles and masks and creating nonexistent characters.

Comment: Maybe the first line is a reference to rot13(20gu Praghel Sbk)

Comment: @LinuxBlanket good suggestion, gonna add it in

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully I'm not reading too much into things.

> fate?

Line 1

> fate drives history.

Line 2

> The greek goddess Clotho spins the 'thread' of fate. Thread is many fibers (hairs) twisted together (in a braid).

Line 3

> Fate makes unpredictable and chance things happen.

Line 4

> Standing in line means not 'cutting' the line. Atropos cuts the thread of fate when a mortal is supposed to die.

Line 5

> Assuming that one's 'turn in the shade' means one's turn in the spotlight/fame, then fate should play a role in determining whether an actor gets a lucky break.

Of course I could be completely off :)